# Type mismatch in Scala. Found List[Int] required List[?]

Tags: scala

Could someone give me a tip why did I get this error?

```
object TestObject  {
    def main (args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
        val list = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
        val lastElem = findLast(list)  <-------------------------- Here is a problem
    }

    def findLast[T](ls : List[T]) : T = {
        if(ls.isEmpty) throw new Exception("List is empty")
        else if(ls.tail.isEmpty) ls.head
        else findLast(ls.tail)

    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
type mismatch;  found   : List[Int]  required: List[?]
```

Comment: what version of Scala are you using? This compiles fine for me with both Scala 2.11.0 and 2.10.4.

Comment: 2.9.2. It seems that's a little bit outdated version .. I'll try with the newest one.

Comment: Hum, even with 2.9.2, it still works. Are you sure there is no difference between your code pasted above and the one you run (except for the "<------ Here is a problem")?

Comment: @gourlaysama: Yes, it's exactly the same code, I'm sure.

Comment: Compiles fine for me - how are you compiling it? If you are using Eclipse, you might want to clean the project and restart Eclipse - I sometimes get spurious errors that are fixed this way.

Comment: With Scala 2.11.0 it still doesn't work for me. I tried Project -> clean as well. My Eclipse is 4.3 (Kepler).

Comment: Try compiling from the command line or sbt. Eclipse tends to go ... _strange_. This will allow to determine if the problem is with your Scala install, or your Eclipse install.

Comment: Just to mention it: the functionality of getting the last element is already covered for `List`s. Just call `list.last`.

Comment: You're probably doing this as a learning exercise, but I just wanted to make sure that you knew that `List` instances have a `last` and `lastOption` method built in. `lastOption` is especially nice since it lets you handle empty lists without needing to throw an exception.

Comment: Form me also everything is all right. Also if you are this for learning purpose I suggest another solution:

       ` def newFindLast[T](ls: List[T]): T = ls match {
        case last::Nil => last
        case head::tail => newFindLast(tail)
        case Nil => throw new RuntimeException("empty list")
        }`

Comment: This problem resolved for me after restarting the Scala REPL.